# Slick can't connect to mssql database

Tags: sql-server, scala, jdbc, slick

I would like to use Slick (3.2.3) to connect to a MSSQL database.

Currently, my project is the following.

In `application.conf`, I have

```
somedbname = {
  driver = "slick.jdbc.SQLServerProfile$"
  db {
    host = "somehost"
    port = "someport"
    databaseName = "Recupel.Datawarehouse"
    url = "jdbc:sqlserver://"${somedbname.db.host}":"${somedbname.db.port}";databaseName="${somedbname.db.databaseName}";"
    user = "someuser"
    password = "somepassword"
  }
}
```

The "somehost" looks like XX.X.XX.XX where X's are numbers.

My `build.sbt` contains

```
name := "test-slick"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion in ThisBuild := "2.12.7"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.2.3",
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick-hikaricp" % "3.2.3",
  "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-nop" % "1.6.4",
  "com.microsoft.sqlserver" % "mssql-jdbc" % "7.0.0.jre10"
)
```

The file with the "main" object contains

```
import slick.basic.DatabaseConfig
import slick.jdbc.JdbcProfile
import slick.jdbc.SQLServerProfile.api._

import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration._


  val dbConfig: DatabaseConfig[JdbcProfile] = DatabaseConfig.forConfig("somedbname")

  val db: JdbcProfile#Backend#Database = dbConfig.db

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    try {

      val future = db.run(sql"SELECT * FROM somettable".as[(Int, String, String, String, String,
        String, String, String, String, String, String, String)])

      println(Await.result(future, 10.seconds))

    } finally {
      db.close()
    }


  }

}
```

This, according to all the documentation that I could find, should be enough to connect to the database. However, when I run this, I get

```
[error] (run-main-0) java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: somedbname.db - Connection is not available, request timed out after 1004ms.
[error] java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: somedbname.db - Connection is not available, request timed out after 1004ms.
[error]         at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createTimeoutException(HikariPool.java:548)
[error]         at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:186)
[error]         at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:145)
[error]         at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:83)
[error]         at slick.jdbc.hikaricp.HikariCPJdbcDataSource.createConnection(HikariCPJdbcDataSource.scala:14)
[error]         at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$BaseSession.<init>(JdbcBackend.scala:453)
[error]         at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$DatabaseDef.createSession(JdbcBackend.scala:46)
[error]         at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$DatabaseDef.createSession(JdbcBackend.scala:37)
[error]         at slick.basic.BasicBackend$DatabaseDef.acquireSession(BasicBackend.scala:249)
[error]         at slick.basic.BasicBackend$DatabaseDef.acquireSession$(BasicBackend.scala:248)
[error]         at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$DatabaseDef.acquireSession(JdbcBackend.scala:37)
[error]         at slick.basic.BasicBackend$DatabaseDef$$anon$2.run(BasicBackend.scala:274)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
[error]         at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
[error] Nonzero exit code: 1
```

Perhaps related and also annoying, when I run this code for the second (and subsequent) times, I get the following error instead:

```
Failed to get driver instance for jdbcUrl=jdbc:sqlserver://[...]
```

which forces me to kill and reload sbt each time.

What am I doing wrong? Worth noting: I can connect to the database with the same credential from a software like valentina.

Comment: Which Java version are you running on?

Comment: @MarkRoottevel java 10.0.1.
Probably not a good idea... Do you think that I should downgrade to java 8?

Comment: The error itself means that Hikari can't get a connection, which either means the pool is exhausted or it can't create connections. Given you used the Java 10 driver, I had hoped it might have been something simple like using Java 8, but alas. Only other thing I can think of is something like the driver not being loaded automatically; you may need to specify it explicitly in the config or load it yourself first. Given I don't know slick, nor Scala, I'm not sure how or where though.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thanks for the suggestion, I'll try to look into explicitly specifying the driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @MarkRotteveel, and following [this link](https://leaks.wanari.com/2016/08/17/enviroment-dependent-database-drivers-slick/), I found a solution.

First, I explicitly set the driver, adding the line

```
driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
```

in the db dictionary, after `password = "somepassword"`.

Secondly, the default timeout (after one second) appears to be too short for my purposes, and therefore I added the line
`connectionTimeout = "30 seconds"`
after the previous `driver` line, still in the `db` dictionary.

Now it works.